# openSSl - Parsing subjectAltName with ASCII and UTF-8 characters

Tags: utf-8, openssl

a SubjectAltName contains a mix of ASCII and UTF-8 characters such as:

6DC3C16E - m(small a with acute)n

I'm using X509_NAME_oneline to parse and getting mixed escape sequences like 'm\xC3\xA1n'

Is there an openssl function which would return a full UTF-8 string?

Thanks

John

Answer (score 0):

`"m\xC3\xA1n"` *is* a full UTF-8 string.  UTF-8 is a variable length encoding, and all of the ASCII characters (which have codepoints less than 128) are encoded identically in ASCII and UTF-8.  The character `m`, for example, is just the single byte `0x6d` in both ASCII and UTF-8.